# ios8 push: get token when developer/distribution ok, but now it's not working after the app has been released on the appstore

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I made an app that use push notifications:

The push notifications work both with distribution and developer scheme but now when the app is available on the app store, I can't get the device token!

Users get the popup and even answering "yes", I can't get the token.

The app has been released 1 hour ago, any suggestion?

**edit:**

The app has been released 1 week ago for the first time and there wasn't the push notification.
It's possible that xcode didn't update my new provisioning profile when signin the app?

Comment: 1) Can you post some of the code where you get the token off the device?
2) Can you verify that your push certificate is of the type: APNs Production iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you had previously released the app without push notification certificates and then pushed an updated with push notification certificates, you have to create a new provisioning profile with the new push notification certs and then build/release your app with that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved! Xcode didn't update the certificate download during the archive operation.